# What would make a historically accurate / appropriate biblical Goliath?

Tags: ancient-history

When I see depictions of David and Goliath almost always they wreak with white culture and inspiration.

Even the biblical account is badly represented, let alone the historical aspect. For instance, not many pictures depict Goliath having SIX fingers, which if they read the biblical account before drawing they might have noticed this.

**What would make a historically accurate / appropriate biblical Goliath?**

Comment: There are a lot of questions here, and not all of them pertain to worldbuilding. What a Canaanite warrior might look like could be a question for the [History SE](http://history.stackexchange.com/) for example.

Comment: Right now you're asking too many questions. Please focus on one and try to make sure it's objectively answerable, otherwise it'll be hard to provide a definitive answer and this question will probably get closed. Currently, it's much too broad and probably too subjective.

Comment: I agree with @DaaaahWhoosh; this is pretty broad. I'd recommend reducing the number of questions to 1, such as asking about his proportions and size. That said, I'm not sure how this is about worldbuilding; it seems like it's asking for an analysis of the Biblical account of Goliath.

Comment: It can be tough to figure out which stackexchange to post in, because not everyone considers the bible as history (hence some aspects of my question would be laughed at in a historical arena) and Christianity stackexchange can have it's unique issues as well - lastly Judaism stackexchange seems appropriate but I thought it most appropriate here first. Will change the question around?

Comment: Question changed, I've simply put out the title as the question and left the remainder as possible notes to consider.

Comment: @Pipsqweek Religious texts aside, I don't think the historical presence of Canaan can be doubted. They had many conflicts with Egypt, and they (or a similar empire) even conquered parts of it for a time, becoming known as the Hyksos. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyksos#/media/File:Ibscha.jpg) is one depiction of them by the Egyptians.

Comment: You might want to check out the video series by Ray Vanderlaan. Most manuscripts place him at a little over 6 feet tall, although the KJV translation puts him closer to 9 feet tall. The philistines were closely related to the phoenicians, and also the the cultures that we common to what would later become Greece. There are places in Israel today still named for him (Ayn Jalut for example). He obviously had a major impact on his world, beyond what we see in the biblical account.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are a few things I would advise you to consider.

For starters, everyone in the old testament would be middle eastern. So he'd look very much like the others, or this would (likely) have been pointed out.

Second, there's the psychological aspect. The story is that, in order to prevent an all out battle, it was offered that Goliath would fight any man of their army one-on-one. This could indicate that he was just a large man (6 feet, or 2 metres tall). Perhaps one with an added deformity (the six fingers, which does happen naturally, if infrequently).

Third, there's the plausible implication that Goliath is a [Nephil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nephilim), though I've not come across any that support this theory. But, if you want to go that route, you can see what Nephilim looked like, and base it on that.

Fourth, there's the fact that Goliath was a soldier in the army. Though it stands to reason he'd stand out anyway, he wasn't a general so he needs to follow the same rules as all the other soldiers. Whatever he wears, or is allowed to wear, needs to also apply to everyone else. So if you want the accurate version, he needs to stand out as little as is possible from his compatriots.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the use of nephilim is a metaphor in the original Hebrew.

Comment: @Joshua I'm pretty sure the bible itself was a metaphor, but that isn't my point. This is a question about possibilities, I offered that.